# salesforce record object to string

Tags: php, casting, salesforce

I am trying to parse this object saleforce returns, however having no luck since it is not a String and I do not know how to make it a String.

Current code for the query:

```
<?php
    define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
    require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
    require_once ('../userAuth.php');
    try {
      $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
      $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
      $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
      $query = 'SELECT DataIncluded__c from GMC_Contract__c limit 5';
      $response = $mySforceConnection->query(($query));
      foreach ($response->records as $record) {
        print_r($record);
        print_r("<br>");
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->faultstring;
    }
    ?>
```

Here when printed/run returns something like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataIncluded__c] => 8 )
stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataIncluded__c] => 11 )
stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataIncluded__c] => 5 )
```

Assuming 3 records. I would like just to get the numbers instead, so it prints 8 then 11 then 5.

However substring does not work, and my attempts to change into a string have not worked. Any suggestion on how I could do this?

Comment: When you print_r($record->Id), what is the output ?

Comment: Nothing, just a blank page. Sorry

Comment: @FredtheMan check my edited ans

Comment: @coder I changed my comment on it, still does not work though.

Comment: @FredtheMan i have changed my ans plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
echo $record->DataIncluded__c
```

instead of

```
print_r($record)
```

because $record is an object and Id is an array.

Comment: Now says, trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: what are u getting after using print_r($response->records) b4 foreach

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataIncluded__c] => 8 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataIncluded__c] => 11 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => [DataIncluded__c] => 5 ) )